# Why is my Wi-Fi File Transfer speed slow?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-transfer

I have made one Windows 10 PC FTP server and using another Windows 10 PC to push files on server. Here are details about network speed:

- Wi-Fi router is 802.11n with speed 300Mbps.
- Both PCs show speed of Wi-Fi 72Mbps (When I click network name in Network and Sharing Center).
- There's no congestion of network.

But, my files are being pushed at much slower rate: 1-2 MBps i.e. 8-16 Mbps (stats shown by NetBalancer). Why?

How to utilize full 72Mbps? Is it possible to use full 300Mbps?

Comment: You need to remember that wireless is a half-duplex medium, so you really get much less bandwidth than the reported overall bandwidth. It is also a shared medium, so any other Wi-Fi in the same frequency range will lower you actual bandwidth since Wi-Fi will stop and share the frequency. There is also the problem of wireless interference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will relate to external noise - although your devices can "hear each other" at 72 mbps, they can also hear anything else.  Other things are eating into that channel and reducing the performance.  You may not be able to do much without getting co-operation of your neighbours and/or grounding/eliminating the source of noise or moving to the quieter 5 gig band (eg 803.11ac)

You can try changing channels, getting more directional aerials and/or moving the AP.   If the AP has MIMO, you can try and re-orientate some of the antennas.  In real life, you can't expect to get anywhere near stated performance (because they test in a lab with an artificially low noise floor for a start, and big packet overheads).